# How to direct my index to MediaWiki index.php

Tags: apache2, mediawiki, lamp

I'm new to all of this honestly, I'm not even sure if i'm asking the question correctly. Basically I have a LAMP server setup to run mediawiki. I can get to by typing localhost/Wiki but I'd to only have to use localhost and it take me to the Main page of the wiki. Right now when I type it I just get a file browser (I removed the default apache2 index.html from /var/www/html. Another note to add is my Wiki index.php is under /var/www/html/Wiki/index.php. Let me know if this question is understandable as I am new.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up [URL rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/) (which is a way to tell the webserver how to translate the URL into a file system path - the default is something like `<URL path>` -> `/var/www/html/<URL path>` but you can do almost anything with the right configuration). There is a [MediaWiki URL rewriting guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) but if your wiki is accessible  from the internet it's easier to use the [Redwerks short URL builder](http://shorturls.redwerks.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The right way to achieve this, is to install mediawiki on `/var/www/html`

But here is a quick and dirty way do redirect.

Create the file `/var/www/html/index.html` with the following lines:

```
<html><head><title>redirect</title>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://localhost/Wiki">
</head><body></body></html>
```

So, when you go to `http://localhost` you will be redirected to `http://localhost/Wiki`

Comment: Those are both really bad ways. The first means nothing else can use `var/www/html`, the second slows page load down by doing an unnecessary redirect. (Also, MediaWiki probably should not have been installed under `var/www/html` in the first place - as the name suggests, that's meant for simple HTML files, not complex PHP applications.)

Comment: I believe he wasn't looking for best practices. He wants to access the wiki directly on `http://localhost`, so obviously he won't use the root page for anything else. Also, apache does not have a  folder for each filetype. `/var/www/html` is the default folder (at least on ubuntu installs from apt) to put all the files for your applications. There is no such thing as `/var/www/php`, unless you create, but then you should access by the corresponding url, `http://localhost/php`

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion after thinking a bit more about. Unfortunately, StackOverflow does not seem to allow retracting -1 votes :( Best practice is IMO to put stuff in `/srv/mediawiki` or `/var/mediawiki` or something like that, and set up an URL rewrite; just dropping stuff in the HTML folder is inefficient and insecure. But I can see how simplicity is more important for someone just familiarizing themselves with running a LAMP server, especially if it's a local one, and especiall given how user-unfriendly mod_rewrite is.

Comment: (as it turns out you have to do a mock edit to be able to change votes.)